# Error in CSV file while programatically parsing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a UI web application, where CSV file is uploaded and I programmatically parse file contents using JavaScript. Once in a while, I see these files, though there is nothing wrong with file visibly when I open it, it throws error when uploaded. When I debug, I see a difference. Ideally in positive scenario, CSV file is read line by line, and 
each column is read into each value in an array. But the error file, entire line is read into a single value in array. I don't know how to fix this. I tried to split that one item with comma and continue. For me that is not working. Because sometimes single column can have multiple values. That means, out of multiple values, each value is split and placed as a single value in array. I need each column read as a single value in array even if that column has multiple values. Then I will further loop thru multiple values. I tried to post images to help. But I don't have 10 reputations to post images.

Here is the javascript code I use to parse each line.

```
    function processData(csv) {
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    var lines = [];
    for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length-1; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split('|');
            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<data.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
    }

   return lines;
 }

angular.forEach(lines, function(line, index)  {
   obj.role=line[1].trim();
   obj.id = line[2].trim();
   obj.entitlements = line[3].trim();
}
```

Comment: Somewhat confusing, but you have an array, `lines`, and in that array you keep pushing other arrays named `tarr`, so you have an array of array, and `lines[0]` would get the first array in the array, and it most likely doesn't have a `trim()` function, unless you added one ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my code in the question